# Eclipse RCP - How to shutdown before workbench initializes

Tags: java, rcp, e4

I have a similar setup to below:

```xml
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="%product.name"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
      <property
           name="lifeCycleURI"
           value="bundleclass://plugin-id/package.LifeCycle">
     </property>
     .... more properties ...
```

```java
public class LifeCycle
{
  @PostConstruct
  public void doWork()
  {
    // Show a login screen. If the user cancels out of it, shut down
    // the application. 
  }
}
```

In the scenario above, what is the correct way to properly shutdown the application?  If I do:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close()
```

I get an error since it's not initialized yet.  If I do:

```
System.exit(0)
```

then I kill all other things on the JVM (Even though it is suggested to do it here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html)

Any ideas/suggestions on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlatformUI` is not available in an e4 application, do not try and use it.

`@PostConstruct` is too early to do anything in the LifeCycle class. The first point you should try and do anything is the `@PostContextCreate` method.

You can inject `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench` and call the `close` method to shutdown the e4 application. However the workbench is not available until the application startup is complete so you need to wait for this event.

```
public class LifeCycle
{
  @PostContextCreate
  public void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext context, IEventBroker eventBroker)
  {
    ...

    eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE,
                          new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler(eventBroker, context));
  }
}


class AppStartupCompleteEventHandler implements EventHandler
{
 private IEventBroker _eventBroker;
 private IEclipseContext _context;


 AppStartupCompleteEventHandler(IEventBroker eventBroker, IEclipseContext context)
 {
   _eventBroker = eventBroker;
   _context = context;
 }

 @Override
 public void handleEvent(final Event event)
 {
   _eventBroker.unsubscribe(this);

   IWorkbench workbench = _context.get(IWorkbench.class);

   workbench.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  One last question.  With the code you provided the application is briefly shown on the screen before the workbench closes. Is there a clean way of preventing this?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could try System.exit but I think that could leave the workspace in a mess.

Answer (score 0):

System.exit() is the only way to currently abort the E4 startup if you are using the SWT renderer.

If you use the JavaFX renderer from e(fx)clipse you can return FALSE from @PostContextCreate to shutdown.

For more information see this blog: 
http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/11/03/efxclipse-1-1-new-features-api-to-restart-your-e4-app-on-startup/

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the SWT renderer.